# Python tkinter Slider control

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to control the Speed of the images animation using the slider. So im trying to do the following but instead I get many images reappearing on the same canvas when i vary the slider. I want to vary the time interval between one image and the next using the slider.

```
from tkinter import *
#import tkFont
import random
from time import sleep 
root = Tk()

class App:

    def __init__(self, master):
        frame = Frame(master)
        frame.pack()
        scale = Scale(frame, from_=0, to=100, command=self.update)
        scale.grid(row=0)

    def update(self, duty):

        #Importing the images. They are named a1.gif, a2.gif...a7.gif
        frame=[]
        for i in range(1,10):
            fname="CORE\\a"+str(i)+".gif"
            frame+=[PhotoImage(file=fname)]
        wrap = Canvas(root, width=200, height=140)
        wrap.pack()

        def do_animation(currentframe):
                def do_image():
                        wrap.create_image(100,70,image=frame[currentframe], tag='ani')
                # Delete the current picture if one exists
                wrap.delete('ani')
                try:
                        do_image()
                except IndexError:
                        # End of image list reached, start over at the first image 
        #- works for an arbitrary number of images
                        currentframe = 0
                        do_image()
                wrap.update_idletasks() #Force redraw
                currentframe = currentframe + 1
                # Call myself again to keep the animation running in a loop
                root.after(100, do_animation, currentframe)
        # Start the animation loop just after the Tkinter loop begins
        root.after(100, do_animation, 0)

app = App(root)
#app.geometry("800x480")
root.mainloop()
python
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're creating a new canvas every time, and not using the speed from the slider. I think this is what you want.

```
from tkinter import *
#import tkFont
import random
from time import sleep 
root = Tk()

class App:

    def __init__(self, master):
        frame = Frame(master)
        frame.pack()
        self.scale = Scale(frame, from_=0, to=1000)
        self.scale.grid(row=0)
        self.wrap = Canvas(root, width=200, height=140)
        self.wrap.pack()
        self.update()

    def update(self):

        #Importing the images. They are named a1.gif, a2.gif...a7.gif
        frame=[]
        for i in range(1,10):
            fname="CORE\\a"+str(i)+".gif"
            frame+=[PhotoImage(file=fname)]

        def do_animation(currentframe):

            def do_image():

                self.wrap.create_image(100,70,image=frame[currentframe], tag='ani')
            # Delete the current picture if one exists
            self.wrap.delete('ani')
            try:
                do_image()
            except IndexError:
                # End of image list reached, start over at the first image 
                #- works for an arbitrary number of images
                currentframe = 0
                do_image()
            self.wrap.update_idletasks() #Force redraw
            currentframe = currentframe + 1
            # Call myself again to keep the animation running in a loop
            root.after(self.scale.get(), do_animation, currentframe)
        # Start the animation loop just after the Tkinter loop begins
        root.after(100, do_animation, 0)

app = App(root)
#app.geometry("800x480")
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: That's amazing, it works, Thank you very much. I understand where i went wrong.